# Facebook marketing api audience limit

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads-api

When using marketing api

About this part...

> You can **add an unlimited number of records to an audience**, but **only a
>   maximum of 10000 at a time**. It may take up to 1 hour before Facebook
>   adds users to an audience, and up to 24 hours for deleting users from
>   an audience.

Is there limit adding user to audience per hour to 10000?

or

when calling

```
$emails = array(
'test1@example.com',
'test2@example.com',
'test3@example.com',
);
$audience>addUsers($emails,CustomAudienceTypes::EMAIL);
```

there is limit of 10000 data in $emails each call?

I can't seem find clear explanation, and already post it through facebook marketing developer community group, but still no answer.

**My current understanding** there is limit of 10000 data in $emails each call. Not sure though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that it is for each call. I have uploaded around 75,000 before and had to use multiple calls.